# How do I put an event handler block on a custom class

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I want to make a global tooltip-style class that has different actions depending on context, how can I put an event handler block on a specific action such as tap? e.g. :

```
MyClass *toolTip = [MyClass new];
toolTip.text = @"Here is a tip, click here to do something";
toolTip.tapHandler = ^{
    //Custom actions here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you want to define a handler property of blocks. You can define such a property like this.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^tapHander)(void);
@end
```

Or, you can use a typedef to make it clearer.

```
typedef void (^HandlerBlock)(void);

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) HandlerBlock tapHandler;
@end
```

Comment: cool, how would I then execute that block upon a button press for example?

Comment: you just call `toolTip.tapHandler()`

Comment: thanks!, also, I think the block should be declared as (nonatomic, copy) ?